# Cannot connect to UserPC\SQLExpress

Tags: sql-server

I just installed SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008. For the username 'sa', I tried to change the password and login through SQL authentication but it failed.

I tried to create a new new user too and login. While I try to login in to the SQL management Studio, this error is given - > Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzq6i.jpg

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Verify that "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" is selected in the Server authentication section of your server's Security properties.

Comment: You may also have to restart the SQL Service after changing this setting (I did). Notes also at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/01/17/sql-server-fix-login-failed-for-user-username-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection-microsoft-sql-server-error-18452/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SQL server is not properly installed.check  computer>manage >services and applications ... if you can see SQL server under that its install is successful. if not the problem is with the installation

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your SQL Server. Looks like the service is not accepting the connections.

Comment: Did a restart but I can't login with 'sa' user too.  Any suggestions?