# Login failed in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot connect to UserPC\SQLExpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638222/cannot-connect-to-userpc-sqlexpress)

I have been struggling to find a solution for this from long but in vain. I recently installed SQL Server Management Studio Express and tried to login with SQL authentication with 'sa' username. It was giving me error 233, so I enabled NamedPipes, Shared Memory and TCP IP from Configuration Manager.

Now, I when I try to login, it shows an Error:

> Login failed for the user ''. Erorr: 18456

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUzox.jpg]

I checked the server error logs and they were showing me

> 2011-01-07 01:35:12.47 spid17s     Error: 17054, **Severity: 16, State: 1.**

Comment: Are you sure you are entering right username/password?

Comment: Did you try with "sa" as the username, or "sarin"?

Comment: @Hippo: I tried with 'sa' as well. http://i.imgur.com/EoAyd.jpg

Comment: Duplicate (same user, same symptoms) of [Cannot connect to UserPC\SQLExpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638222/cannot-connect-to-userpc-sqlexpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging in with "Windows Authentication" first and create a new user with a password. You can use this new username/password to login and find out if you are using the right user/pwd combination.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the user you are trying to login with (`sarin`) is a valid user in the database and has the right permissions.

Comment: I had created a new user 'sarin' and changed the password from the Management Studio. Here's the screenshot showing the user 'sarin' http://i.imgur.com/6Enfx.jpg

Comment: @user458790 - And you gave it the right permissions?

Comment: Are these permissions correct? http://i.imgur.com/KxBBY.jpg

Comment: But the error still remains. Can it be something related to allowing remote connection to SQL Server? :-/ I read it somewhere. How to enable this remote connection?

Comment: @Cipher - That would indeed be needed. I believe you already did that.

Comment: I did these steps too: In Configuration Manager, Protocol for MSSQLSERVER & TCP/IP in detail pane>IP Address tab. 

IP1=> Active=Yes, Enabled=Yes,IP Address =<machine ip address>, TCP Dynamic Port=Empty, TCP Port=1433

IP2=> Active=Yes, Enabled=Yes,IP Address =127.0.0.1, TCP Dynamic Port=Empty, TCP Port=1433

IP3=> TCP Dynamic Port=Empty, TCP Port=1433

And click ok & Restart your SQL Server Service. Run your ASP.Net application its working.

Nothing but the same :-(